# Habitat Home Platform Docker installation error

Tags: powershell, docker

I'm flowing the blog from "Viet Hoang" to install the Habitat.Home.Platform Docker example. I followed all the instructions and when I execute ".\build.ps1 -DeploymentTarget DockerBuild" the script is failing.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\sat\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll' or one of its dependencies.
```

The package under the "sat" folder is the correct version ("Sitecore Azure Toolkit 2.4.0-r02514.1001") and the "Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll" exists.
Previously, I did manage to run the Sitecore v9.3 Docker example and solved all the issues and verified Sitecore.
**Sitecore v9.3 Docker - worked for me:**
https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/11/12/playing-around-with-the-set-up-of-sitecore-docker-images/

**Following this Blog - which is failing:**
 
"https://buoctrenmay.com/2019/12/23/sitecore-xp-9-3-0-and-sxa-9-3-0-demo-habitat-home-setup-guide/"

```
Generate-Dacpacs
========================================
Executing: &"C:/Projects/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform/scripts/Packaging/generate-dacpac.ps1" -SitecoreAzureToolkitPath c:\sat -updatePackagePath c:\Deploy\update\package.update -securityPackagePath c:\Deploy\update\security.dacp
ac -destinationPath C:\Projects\Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform\docker\images\windows\demo-xp-sqldev\Data
Cake.exe : An error occurred when executing task 'Generate-Dacpacs'.
At C:\Projects\Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform\build.ps1:253 char:1
+ &$CAKE_EXE $cakeArguments
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (An error occurr...erate-Dacpacs'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error: 
One or more errors occurred.

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\sat\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

Does anybody know what might the missing Dependencies are?

Comment: Are you running it in PowerShell 6 (Core)? Try PowerShell or earlier, the blue one.

Comment: * PowerShell 5 or earlier

Comment: Hi. I'm using PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on this file "C:\sat\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll" and check the "Unblock Checkbox" and re-run the script.

This will solve this issue.